# Populating select option dynamically with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

There will be two drop down lists,

First have the list of mobile vendor, and the second have the list of models per vendor.

When one select a vendor from the first drop down list, the second drop down list should populate with relevant model for that vendor dynamically. **This is for mobile web site, it's better to use [jquery-mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/)**

The option values for the second will in a json map.

```
  <select class="mobile-vendor">
    <option value="motorola">Motorola</option>
    <option value="nokia">Nokia</option>
    <option value="android">Android</option>
  </select>

 selectValues = {"nokia"   : {"N97":"download-link", 
                              "N93":"download-link"}, 
                 "motorola": {"M1":"download-link",
                              "M2":"download-link"}}

<select class="model">
    <option></option>
</select>
```

For example, if the user selects nokia in the first drop down list, the second drop down list should have N97, N93 as the options.

Comment: You have a problem with your json array, it doesn't work the way you intend it to. You can only have one instance of each item with same name, have a look here: http://jsfiddle.net/niklasvh/uJUS2/

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**EDIT:** New javascript to take into account your updated json structure:

```
$(function() {
    var selectValues = {
        "nokia": {
            "N97": "http://www.google.com",
            "N93": "http://www.stackoverflow.com"
        },
        "motorola": {
            "M1": "http://www.ebay.com",
            "M2": "http://www.twitter.com"
        }
    };

    var $vendor = $('select.mobile-vendor');
    var $model = $('select.model');
    $vendor.change(function() {
        $model.empty().append(function() {
            var output = '';
            $.each(selectValues[$vendor.val()], function(key, value) {
                output += '<option>' + key + '</option>';
            });
            return output;
        });
    }).change();

    // bonus: how to access the download link
    $model.change(function() {
        $('#download-link').attr('href', selectValues[$vendor.val()][$model.val()]).show();
    });
});
```

Working example is available [in jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/greglockwood/T7LJY/3).

Note that this should work with jQuery mobile just fine.

Comment: I've updated the json map, can you check & update your answer? Thanks for the answer!

Comment: @KugathasanAbimaran What is the point of having the "download-link" value for each property in the nested object?

Comment: Once the user select the item from second drop down list, he will be able to download that application corresponding to the vendor-model.

Comment: @KugathasanAbimaran Updated with complete code, and updated jsFiddle as well. Should do what you need.

Comment: This method works with `http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js`, but, not work with `http://code.jquery.com/mobile/latest/jquery.mobile.min.js`

Comment: @KugathasanAbimaran From what I remember of jQuery mobile, you have to reference *both* jQuery and jQuery Mobile scripts for it to work.

Comment: With the above you won't be able to select the value of the second select in ie7 or ie8, you need the option value attribute set too. So so you need something like:$('select.model').append($("<option></option>").val(this.toString()).html(this.toString()));