# jQuery autocomplete with ajax json phph

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax, autocomplete

I'm trying to find a way to use jQuery autocomplete with php source getting data via an ajax json object list from the server.
But Select is empty :

```
<script>
    $('#id_client_nc').autocomplete({
        source: function( request, response ) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "<?php echo URL::base(); ?>commerce/client/selectajax/"+$(this).val(),
                dataType: "jsonp",
                data: {
                    q: request.term
                },
                success: function( data ) {
                    var sel = $("#id_client_nc");
                    sel.empty();

                    $("#id_client_nc").empty();
                    sel.append('<option value="">--sélectionner--</option>');
                    for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
                        sel.append('<option value="' + data[i].client_id + '" >' + data[i].client_nom +'</option>');
                    }
                    $("#id_client_nc").select2("destroy");
                    $("#id_client_nc").select2();        
                }
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

html :

```
<select name="" class="selecttwo-s span12 id_client" id="id_client_nc"> </select>
```

Comment: Similar question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8090457/populating-select-option-dynamically-with-jquery

Answer (score 0):

The `response` parameter is a function that you call with your autocomplete data as a parameter. So in your example, assuming your data is a JSON formatted array, you would write

```
response(JSON.parse(data));
```

to pass your result to the autocomplete window.