# How to display certain columns from a table using HTML listbox and SQL code?

Tags: html, mysql, sql

Good day, I have the following request: A table with 2 columns: Country and Capital. The table contains every country with every capital from the world. There is a listbox where I can select the country and it will display only the capital from that country.

I created with HTML a listbox which let me to choose a Country:

```
< select> <br>
< option Country = "Brasil"> Brasil < /option> <br>
< option Country = "... "> .. < /option> <br>
< /select> </br>
```

How can i display a capital using a country from that HTML listbox? I was thinking to create an option for every capital, but then i'd need over 120 **if**-cases. (In SQL)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Populating select option dynamically with jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8090457/populating-select-option-dynamically-with-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

You can generate the select form:

```
<?php 
$req = $pdo->query('SELECT * FROM table');
$rep = $req->fetchAll(); ?>
<select>
foreach($rep as $row) { ?>
  <option value="<?= $row['country'] ?>"><?= $row['country'] ?></option>
<? } ?>
</select>
<?php foreach($rep as $row) { 
  <input style="display:none" id="<?= $row['country'] ?>" value="<?= $row['capital'] ?>" />
<?php } ?>
```

So you will have the select with all country, and an input for each Capital with their Country as id, so you can display it with javascript: (jQuery example)

```
<script>
$('select').change(function() {
  $('input:visible').toggle(); 
  $('input[id='+$(this).val()+']').toggle();
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch the countries and ther capitals from the database using the following code in `php`

```
//This is where you put the fetched data
$entries = Array();

//Make new connection
$connection  = new mysqli("127.0.0.1", "username", "password", "databasename");

//Create prepared statement
$statement = $connection->prepare("SELECT `country`, `capital` FROM `table`");
$statement->bind_result($country, $capital);

//Put the fetched data in the result array
while($statement->fetch()) {
  $entry = Array();

  $entry['country'] = $country;
  $entry['capital'] = $capital;

  $entries[] = $entry;
}

//Close the statement and connection
$statement->close();
$connection->close();
```

Next, you make the HTML `select` objects. It's important that the order of countries remains the same as the order of the capitals.

```
<!-- Country selection -->
<select id="select-country">
 <?php $i = 0;
       foreach ($entries as $c) { ?>
       <option data-country="<?php echo $i++; ?>"><?php echo $c['country'] ?></option>
   <?php } ?>
</select>

<!-- Capitals select -->
<select id="select-capital">
  <?php $i = 0;
       foreach ($entries as $c) { ?>
        <option data-capital="<?php echo $i++ ?>"><?php echo $c['capital'] ?></option>
   <?php } ?>
</select>
```

Finally, you add an event listener to the `select` with the id of `select-country` where you listen for the `change` event. Once called, you change the selected index of the second `select` to that of the first. That's why it's important that the order remains the same.

```
<script>
        document.getElementById('select-country').addEventListener('change', function () {
            document.getElementById('select-capital').getElementsByTagName('option')[this.selectedIndex].selected = true;
        });
</script>
```